# How to fix getting error while importing in vs code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to use import functions like import turtle, import pandas, import math,etc. but whenever i import something in my vs code i get error, while that same code runs in another terminal. can someone tell me that how to fix it?

i tried to import math but the code is not executed in vs code

Problem facing during import

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved and the error message? Please share all this in text form, not hidden in screenshots

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.